# Android how to detect if object or obstacle is behind (or in front of) me in a map

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I want to detect if some object is behind me or in front of me in a map. I can get my location, of course, and I have the object location and the travelling direction (bearing). I want to know how to check if in front of me or is behind me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a distance trick . If the distance between me and obstacle increases so it is definitely behind me. In decreases, It's in front of me.